# Date From and To filtering

Tags: c#, date-range

**Context**

So I have a user that will be active between two dates:

```
User.StartDate
User.EndDate
```

During that time, there will be tasks the user can choose to work on.

```
Task.StartDate
Task.EndDate
```

**Note:** The end dates on each of these are nullable.

If no EndDate defined on User, the user will always be active and never leaves.

And if the Task has no end date, the Task will never end and will always be available for users who start after the task does.

Trying to work out a nifty way in C# to get a filtered `List<Task>` of tasks, where the user is active, and the task date range falls in that active period.

**My Solution**

So far this is what I came up with, would anyone suggest better?

```
/// <summary>
/// Filter a list of Task so only tasks falling between dates will be returned.
/// If toDateTime is not defined, then it's considered open ended
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tasks"></param>
/// <param name="fromDateTime"></param>
/// <param name="toDateTime"></param>
/// <returns>A filtered list of tasks</returns>
public List<Task> FilterRatesOnDates(
    List<Task> tasks,
    DateTime fromDateTime,
    DateTime? toDateTime)
{
    tasks = tasks.FindAll(p =>
        ((p.ToDate.HasValue && fromDateTime <= p.ToDate) 
             || !p.ToDate.HasValue)
             && 
         ((toDateTime.HasValue && toDateTime >= p.FromDate)
             || !toDateTime.HasValue)
    );

    return tasks;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar problem recently and was introduced to [Fowler's Range](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/Range.html). Although the examples are not in C# they are easily translated. this is mine:

```
public interface IRange<T>
{
    T Start { get; }
    T End { get; }
    bool Includes(T value);
    bool Includes(IRange<T> range);
}

public class DateRange : IRange<DateTime>
{
    public DateRange(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        Start = start;
        End = end;
    }

    public DateTime Start { get; private set; }
    public DateTime End { get; private set; }

    public bool Includes(DateTime value)
    {
        return (Start <= value) && (value <= End);
    }

    public bool Includes(IRange<DateTime> range)
    {
        return (Start <= range.Start) && (range.End <= End);
    }
}
```

And is used as follows:

```
DateRange range = new DateRange(firstDate, secondDate);
bool inRange = range.Includes(dateToTest);
```

In your case, check that both task dates are in the required range.

Comment: Ok looks good, though am I reading that this always has an end date?

Comment: This is only a skeleton for you to adapt

Comment: That's good just wanted to be sure I was reading correctly. :)